# EC2 Server Instance running RStudio on port 8787 Timing Out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, rstudio-server

I am attempting to run RStudio on an AWS EC2 instance, but it keeps timing out. I am currently following the instructions in this post (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/).

From my research, I realize that this is most often a security group issue. [image]

My instance has access to SSH port 22 and Custom TCP port 8787. I've been troubleshooting using this link (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout).

I have tried using both default VPC and my own, both of which have the following subnet network ACL rules. [image]
[image]

However, my public IPVv4 DNS (http://ec2-18-234-130-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) keeps timing out. I cannot access the login page.

A friend who set up their instance using the first link was successful, and as far as I can tell, I have done everything the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you ssh into the instance, can you curl the rstudio? `curl locahost:8787`?

Comment: Would this be in the "configuring instance details" part?

Comment: Please edit your question to show you are connecting to RStudio. For example, what is the URL? Are you using Port Forwarding? Do you know whether RStudio is actually running on the instance? (You can test it as @Marcin suggested above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RStudio **works fine**. In your URL you have to **provide port number**: 8787

```
http://ec2-18-234-130-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8787
```

As you wrote in the question, it seems you are using the link without the port number.

[image]

p.s.

As you've setup it currently, your traffic to RStudio goes **unencrypted** over HTTP. If you are not fine with that, a quick fix would be to use **ssh tunnel** from the instance to your local workstation. With this can close port 8787 as all traffic goes over port 22 and ssh.

Comment: I tried the link you attached with the 8787 and I am still unsuccessful. Would you know what causes this issue?

Comment: @datascientist2117 The instance works fine, as evident in my answer. If you can't connect, then it must be something else happening, not related to the instance. Maybe you have some firewall on your computer?

Comment: I checked my settings and can confirm that I do not have a firewall. Are you accessing the link through web browser? I have currently tried Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Maybe they block unencrypted connections? You can try from command line: `curl -L http://ec2-18-234-130-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8787`.

Comment: I am now getting this error from the command line. ```Failed to connect to ec2-18-234-130-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 8787: Operation timed out```. It seems like this is an issue unique to my end. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: @datascientist2117 did you ever figure out what the issue was? I'm running into the exact same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Do you access the login page in web browser? If you doing that, you forgot to open port 80/443

Comment: Is there a non-web browser method to access the login page?

Comment: After opening these ports, my EC2 instance will not launch at all.